# How to define a function that calls shiny functions?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to define a function that calls shiny functions with reactive input as arguments. For this example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("do", "Click Me")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    clickFunction<-function(x){
        observeEvent(x, {print("got it")})
    }

    clickFunction(x = input$do)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I expect

> [1] "got it"

when I klick the button "Click Me", but instead there is no output.

How can let observeEvent observe the reactive inputs?

I think it might depend on the enviroment arguments of observeEvent, but I am inexperienced in using them.

Thank you in andvance.

Comment: Usually `observeEvent()` is called from inside `server`. Your example doesn't work as `clickFunction()` is not called (it's not in a reactive environment). The usual way to call `observeEvent()` would be `server <- function(input, output, session) {observeEvent(input$do,{print("got it")})}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `input$do` with a reactive wrapper. The way your example is coded, `input$do` will be evaluated once when the function is called.

```
library(shiny)

clickFunction <- function(x){
  observeEvent(x(), {print("got it")})
}

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(actionButton("do", "Click Me")),
  function(input, output, session){      
    clickFunction(reactive({input$do}))
  }
)
```

Annother way is to quote your event expression, but then `input` has to be in the scope of `clickFunction`

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(actionButton("do", "Click Me")),
  function(input, output, session){
    clickFunction <- function(x){
      observeEvent(x, {print("got it")}, event.quoted = TRUE)
    }

    clickFunction(x = quote(input$do))
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you Gregor, would it please be possible to take a look at a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61914568/10841085)?